# NopCommerce - Conditionally hide payment options

Tags: c#, nopcommerce

Is there a way to conditionally hide certain payment methods based upon some user criteria?

For example:

```
if (!_workContext.CurrentCustomer.IsRegistered()){
    // Hide Credit Card payment method
}
```

The above is just an example, but I have created a custom payment method plugin, and based upon some different things I need to show/hide said payment method from the front end. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are various ways to do so. Payment methods code located at `Nop.Web > View > Checkout > opcPaymentMethods.cshtml` *(one page checkout) nopCommerce 3.90*

```
<ul class="method-list" id="payment-method-block">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PaymentMethods.Count; i++)
    {
        var paymentMethod = Model.PaymentMethods[i];
        var paymentMethodName = paymentMethod.Name;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(paymentMethod.Fee))
        {
            paymentMethodName = T("Checkout.SelectPaymentMethod.MethodAndFee", paymentMethodName, paymentMethod.Fee).Text;
            ...
            ....
        }
    }
</ul>
```

I'm not able find `IsRegistered` property, so I'm using email address here, and check it with plugin system name, if condition matched then skip that payment method.

```
@using Nop.Core.Infrastructure;
@using Nop.Core;

<ul class="method-list" id="payment-method-block">
  @for (int i = 0; i < Model.PaymentMethods.Count; i++)
  {                    
      var customerEmail = EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IWorkContext>().CurrentCustomer.Email;

      var paymentMethod = Model.PaymentMethods[i];

      string _paymentMethodSystemName = paymentMethod.PaymentMethodSystemName;

      if(customerEmail == "admin@yourstore.com")
      {
        if (_paymentMethodSystemName == "Payments.CheckMoneyOrder")
        {
            continue;
        }
      }

      var paymentMethodName = paymentMethod.Name;
  }
  ...
  .....
```

Now, CheckMoneyOrder won't load for admin user.

Comment: Thanks this is what i was needing. Marked as answer.

Comment: Glad I could help!